# django import error - from . import views in urls under app

Tags: python, django, url, import

I did declare like `from . import views` in `urls.py`. 
To use TemplateView, this urls.py is needed.

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, re_path

from . import views

app_name = 'scheduler'

urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^service/(?P<status>\w+)', views.SchedulerView.as_view(), name='schedule-service')
]
```

I think nothing but normal implementation.

Error occurs like the below.

```
 from . import views
ImportError: cannot import name 'views'
```

Older versions django did work. But it's not working in django 2.0

App Structure

```
- server
  - scheduler
    - templatetags
      schedule_status.py
    urls.py
    models.py
    views.py
  - main
    settings.py
    urls.py
  - manage.py
```

I just guess 'scheduler' app's path is incorrect to work "from . import views"
 Is there anyone who solved or check more things. these problem after django 2.0.

ps. sorry, I forgot to add view.py in structure in question. SchedulerView is declared in views.py

Comment: You don't have any file named `views.py`.

Comment: I think views.SchedulerView.as_view() is using to class under views in App. I can say again, It did work before. And this usage is the same at  Django's official page's tutorial.  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial03/

Comment: No. The tutorial has a file called views.py. You do not.

Comment: views.py I did forget to add in question.  SchedulerView is declared in views.py

Answer (score 0):

I did found a solution. python 3.6 has changed something.

I did create directory as views and added scheduler_view.py

and

```
from .views import scheduler_view as view

app_name = 'scheduler'

urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^service/(?P<status>\w+)', view.SchedulerView.as_view(), name='schedule-service')
]
```

it doesn't occur error and runserver as well.

plus I did error occur again in another file. it's for older python.

scheduler_view.py

```
from scheduler import Scheduler -> from scheduler.scheduler import Scheduler
```

I did change it.

http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_concepts/import_traps.html

I wish it's helpful.